# How draw oval image in JLabel

Tags: java, graphics

I want to draw a oval image in a **JLabel**, using **Graphics**. This is my code, but a dont know about Graphics.

```
class imagePanel extends JLabel {
    //private PlanarImage image;

    private BufferedImage buffImage = null;

    private void drawFingerImage(int nWidth, int nHeight, byte[] buff) {
        buffImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        buffImage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, buff);
        Graphics g = buffImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, 140, 150, null);
        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAqzO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the help of setClip() method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731799/bufferedimage-into-circle-shape) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677661/drawing-a-part-of-an-image-java).

when it comes to code it should look like this

```
public class OvalImageLabel extends JLabel {

    private Image image;

    public OvalImageLabel(URL imageUrl) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setClip(new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Float(0f,0f, getWidth(),getHeight()/2));
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }
}
```

and a running application that using this class

```
public class UsageExample extends JPanel {

    public UsageExample() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        OvalImageLabel l;
        try {
            l = new OvalImageLabel(new File("/path/to/image.png").toURI().toURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new UsageExample());
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, Im only use ´g.setClip(new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Float(0f,0f, getWidth(),getHeight()/2));´